# Access form panel from user control?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project, I used a Windows Form and user controls. There is a panel on the form. And I put user controls on it.

When I click a button on the user control, I want to load another user control on the Windows Form panel. I set the panel's modifiers public.

The code I tried is below, this are the used variables:

- `myusercontrolpage1`: this is my first user control
- `myusercontrolpage1`: this is my second user control
- `FrmMain`: this is my main form
- `pnlOrta`: this is my panel I load user control in it

This is the code, which is not working:

```
 Userclasses.myusercontrolpage1 page1 = new Userclasses.myusercontrolpage1();
 Userclasses.myusercontrolpage2 page2 = new Userclasses.myusercontrolpage2();
 FrmMain pnl = new FrmMain();        
 pnl.pnlOrta.Controls.Clear(); 
 pnl.pnlOrta.Controls.Add(page2);
 pnl.pnlOrta.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
 pnl.pnlOrta.BringToFront();
```

When I click a button on the user control, I want to load another user control on a Windows Form panel.

How can I access form's panel from user control and load another user control?

**EDIT:**

I replaced this:

```
FrmMain pnl = new FrmMain();
```

to

```
FrmMain f = (FrmMain)this.ParentForm;
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do, but answering this part of your question:

> How can i access form's panel from
>   usercontrol...

If you know your UserControl is going to be load on Panel, then you can use .Parent property. You can do something like this in your UserControl (suppose it has a button):

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel pnl = this.Parent as Panel;
        if (pnl != null)
        {
            pnl.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```